# Server farm (service plan) SKUs

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, server-farm, azure-rm-template

Is there documentation in the wild that lists the sku names and tiers supported by Azure app service plans (server farms).

eg:
name: "S1",
tier: "Standard" = an S1 Standard.

and
name: "Y1",
tier: "Dynamic" = A function consumption plan.

A list of supported values (is there an Y2 consumption plan?) and the server configurations would really help with planning.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are various ways to find the sku and capabilities for resources. This link references a few options for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-sku-not-available-errors

The current server farm descriptions are:

```
name    Tier        Full name
D1      Shared      an D1 Shared
F1      Free        an F1 Free
B1      Basic       an B1 Basic
B2      Basic       an B2 Basic
B3      Basic       an B3 Basic
S1      Standard    an S1 Standard
S2      Standard    an S2 Standard
S3      Standard    an S3 Standard
P1      Premium     an P1 Premium
P2      Premium     an P2 Premium
P3      Premium     an P3 Premium
P1V2    PremiumV2   an P1V2 PremiumV2
P2V2    PremiumV2   an P2V2 PremiumV2
P3V2    PremiumV2   an P3V2 PremiumV2
I1      Isolated    an I2 Isolated
I2      Isolated    an I2 Isolated
I3      Isolated    an I3 Isolated
Y1      Dynamic     a  function consumption plan
```

to deploy a server farm use this resource definition in ARM:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
  },
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuName')]",
    "tier": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuTier')]"
  }
}
```

alternatively for a consumption plan; you can use a more specific api version:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
  "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "computeMode": "Dynamic",
      "sku": "Dynamic"
  }
}
```

> is there an Y2 consumption plan?

Currently, Azure does not support this, Azure only support one type consumption plan.

More information about this please refer to this [official document:Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview).

Comment: Thank you. Where did you get this list from?

Comment: Deploying to Australia east, and following the guidance: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/…, the compute mode = dynamic, sku = dynamic does not work. The only way to create a consumption plan (is using the sku object), name = Y1, teir = Dynamic.

Comment: @Hoffmania I test it on Azure Portal. Hi, could you provide full links.

Comment: @Hoffmania You could create function app on Azure Portal and Click `Automation options`, like this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/wWPr0). then you will find sku and sku name in the template. Hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted to put together a sample of this not working using "computeMode" and "sku" = dynamic. I've been able to replicate it, but it's a user issue. I was using the apiVersion = 2016-09-01, this version requires the sku object. If you use apiVersion = 2015-04-01 (as documented) the deployment succeeds. In vscode it displays a green squiggly and suggests a fix to 2015-08-01. This breaks the deployment as this requires the sku object too.

Comment: I am hoping the correct answer will point to documentation of the listing of server farms skus or at the very least an api to call.

Comment: @ShuiShengbao is there documentation on the different apiVersions? I find the bizarre apiVersion and lack of clarity an exceptional hindrance for ARM templates... surely you would just always use the most recent?!

Answer (score 9):

Building on Shui...
Use the following fragment in your template:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appServicePlanSkuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        //name  Tier          Full name
        "D1",   //Shared      an D1 Shared
        "F1",   //Free        an F1 Free
        "B1",   //Basic       an B1 Basic
        "B2",   //Basic       an B2 Basic
        "B3",   //Basic       an B3 Basic
        "S1",   //Standard    an S1 Standard
        "S2",   //Standard    an S2 Standard
        "S3",   //Standard    an S3 Standard
        "P1",   //Premium     an P1 Premium
        "P2",   //Premium     an P2 Premium
        "P3",   //Premium     an P3 Premium
        "P1V2", //PremiumV2   an P1V2 PremiumV2
        "P2V2", //PremiumV2   an P2V2 PremiumV2
        "P3V2", //PremiumV2   an P3V2 PremiumV2
        "I1",   //Isolated    an I2 Isolated
        "I2",   //Isolated    an I2 Isolated
        "I3",   //Isolated    an I3 Isolated
        "Y1",   //Dynamic     a  function consumption plan
        "EP1",  //ElasticPremium
        "EP2",  //ElasticPremium
        "EP3"   //ElasticPremium
      ]
    },
    ...
```

Then define Microsoft.Web/serverFarms resource:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "kind": "linux",
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanName')]",
        "reserved": true,
        "targetWorkerCount": 1,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": "[parameters('appServicePlanWorkerSizeId')]",
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('appServicePlanSkuName')]"
      }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Is it enough to just include the "name" property for "sku" or do we have to provide "tier" or anything else?

Comment: Just the name is required

Answer (score 2):

This API provides a list of App Service Plan SKUs available to an existing App Service Plan

`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/{name}/skus?api-version=2016-09-01`

Microsoft documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/appserviceplans/getserverfarmskus)

Comment: don't just post a link to a web page as an answer, instead copy the relevant bits here (and post the link for additional details). Microsoft links especially tend to not be valid forever and your answer could be completely unusable in a few years time.