# Azure - can't create a new web app on an existing service plan

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

**Hello,**

I have a "Basic" App Service plan on Azure.

**Issue: I cannot create a new web app on an existing App Service Plan.**

It only gives the option of creating a new app services plan (but I don't want another app service plan).  No errors.  No explanations. Just options for "new" app service plans.

It used to be a case of create new web app -> select service plan -> choose existing -> select from existing app service plan -> create a web app. Done.

I am trying to create a new web app - there is now a new interface to achieve this - however, when I select a resource group, same region as App Service Plan, there is only the option to "create new app service plan" - but I already have one - it's not appearing in the list.

Things I have tried:

- Looking at resources - memory usage is approx 60-70% - so it doesn't appear to be that.  I even removed a website that was stopped just in case.
- Logging out and back in
- Logging in as original administrator on another PC (not delegated admin as I am).
- Removing an existing web app
- Go through each resource to find a combination that will unveil my app service.

I have both web apps and functions (.net core C#) - can it be something to do with having functions and windows web apps .net core c# working on the same web service?

What am I missing?  I feel it is something obvious.

Thanks.

Comment: you may want to create a bug report. Even if it is not a bug it is an unclear UI that is supposed to be fixed. also have you tried this from visual studio?

Comment: I have just this minute submitted a support request.  I expect to be able to select the app service plan. I haven't gone through with the full process but all seems fine from within Visual Studio 2019 - the plan is shown and it appears I could proceed to create a web app on the existing app service plan.

Comment: @DanAbdn Same here. I am not able to create a new app service from the Azure Portal on the existing plan (even if the resource group is in the same region) but it's working from VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had App Service Plan located in West Europe.

Then, I wanted to add an App also to the West Europe, however the resource group that I selected for this app was located in North Europe. When I changed resource group that was located in West Europe problem was solved.

[image]

Comment: I have tried all the resource groups - I am trying to add to my App Service plan located in north europe using a resource group based also in North Europe.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Setting as answer because it's a valid answer to the problem under normal circumstances, however it was a genuine bug (after quite a few e-mails and trying a development version of the portal devs had fixed something).

Answer (score 2):

[As mentioned in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56594654/1184584) ASP and Function app needs to be in the same location.

In addition to that, in my case the existing App Service Plan turned out to be an ASP that was created for **Consumption Plan** (Y1).

[image]

So, if I need to reuse that ASP, my new function has to use consumption plan.

But, when creating a new function, I did not see anything in the azure portal that allows to pick an existing ASP when selecting consumption plan.

[image]

I was able to work around this by generating the ARM template instead of directly creating the resource in portal. i.e. in the "Review + Create" screen, i would hit "Download a template for automation"

[image]

Then hit deploy, and in the deployment screen, i would update the parameter for the hostingPlan name, and change it to the existing ASP:

[image]

This will create the function in an existing consumption plan ASP.

Credit to this [answer that pointed me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47522889/1184584)

Answer (score 0):

Its something wrong with browser. Try MS Edge instead of Chrome or whatever. Faced agains same issue. In MS Edge it worked